# Convergence of $\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{1}{p_n(p_n+1)}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, prime-numbers

It is well known that

$$
\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=1,
$$

since

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=1-\frac{1}{N-1}.
$$

But what of

$$
\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{1}{p_n(p_n+1)},
$$

where $p_n$ denotes the n$^{\rm th}$ prime? More generally, does the sum

$$
S(k)=\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{1}{p_n^k(p_n+1)^k}
$$

converge? If so, to what?

---

**EDIT**

Since most comments consist of "*it converges using the comparison test*", I would like to specify that I am looking for the **value** of these sums, not a statement about whether they converge or not.

Comment: Convergence is quite trivial, because $\forall n\, p_n>n$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2826155/series-and-sequences-absolute-convergence/2826384#2826384 , greetings.

Comment: If you have a convergent sum of positive terms, then every *subsum* (which takes only a subset of all summands) converges to a smaller number.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy If it is so trivial, could you please say what it converges to? Wolfram Alpha returns "Computation time exceeded", instead of a solution (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convergence+of++sum+(1%2F(Prime(n)(Prime(n)%2B1))),+n%3D1+to+infinity). If it would be trivial I assume WA would give an answer quite rapidly.

Comment: @PreservedFruit What I mean is that it is trivial to show that the series converges to a finite value $S(1)\in \Bbb R$; finding exact value of $S(1)$ is, unfortunately, not that trivial.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Oh ok, thank you. I misunderstood your comment. So there is no way of giving a value to that sum with the current state of math?

Comment: @PreservedFruit I wouldn't say that outright - perhaps, there are some results on subject, I am just unaware of them. But yes, the intuition suggests that no, we can not express $S(1)$ in terms of easier constants/functions.

Comment: It is somehow related to [Artin's constant](http://oeis.org/A001692/a001692.html)

Comment: One does not simply evaluate these kinds of sums (other that numerically). Note for example that the simpler looking sum $\sum \frac{1}{p_n^2}$ does not have a [closed form](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53443/sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-the-primes-squared)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(s)=\sum_p\frac{1}{p^s}$ be [the prime zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html).

$$\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p(p+1)} = \sum_{m\geq 2}(-1)^m P(m) = \sum_{m\geq 2}(-1)^m\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}\log\zeta(km) $$
allows an efficient numerical evaluation of the LHS, which turns out to be pretty close to $\frac{1}{3}$ ($\approx 0.33023$).
I do not believe there is any "nice" closed form for such series or for the similar [Meissel-Mertens constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant), but the same approach applies to the series $\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^s(p+1)^s}$.

A similar technique is to notice that over the interval $\left[0,\frac{1}{5}\right]$ the approximation
$$\frac{x^2}{x+1}\approx \log(1+x^2)-\log(1+x^3)+\frac{3}{2}\log(1+x^4) $$
is extremely accurate, hence
$$ \sum_{p}\frac{1}{p(p+1)}\approx \frac{1}{4}+\sum_{p\geq 5}\left[\log\left(1+\frac{1}{p^2}\right)-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{p^3}\right)+\frac{3}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{p^4}\right)\right] $$
where the RHS can be computed from Euler's product, as
$$\frac{1}{4}-2\log\pi+\log(2^4 3^6 7)+\frac{1}{2}\log(2\cdot 3\cdot 7)-\frac{1}{2}\log(5\cdot 17\cdot 41)-\log(17\cdot 41)-\log\zeta(3)\approx\\ \approx \color{green}{0.330}616\ldots $$
Proving that $\sum_{p\text{ prime}}\frac{1}{p(p+1)}<\frac{1}{3}$ is actually a very nice exercise, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi Jack. Thanks a lot for your excellent response. The first step (i.e., that $\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p(p+1)} = \sum_{m\geq 2}(-1)^m P(m)$ is not immediately obvious to me. Could you please explain it?

Comment: @PreservedFruit: $\frac{1}{p(p+1)}$ is a geometric series, $\frac{1}{p^2}-\frac{1}{p^3}+\frac{1}{p^4}-\frac{1}{p^5}+\ldots$

Comment: Indeed :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

A value with a precision of roughly 683 decimal digits is given in http://oeis.org/A179119

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if wrong:

A proof of the 'trivial':

$a_k= \dfrac{1}{k(k+1)}$, $k=1,2,3,...$

$b_k = \dfrac{1}{p_n(p_n+1)}$ for

$k=p_n, n=1,2,3...$

$b_k =0$ for $k\not = p_n$, $n=1,2, 3,..$

Then $b_k \le a_k$ , $k \in \mathbb{N}.$

Hence?